# user inputs starting with two numbers if over 50 done is not more until reached 50

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Ask the user for two positive numbers and add them together.  If the answer is 50 or more then display the answer in a user friendly format.  If the answer is below 50, ask the user to continue to select more numbers until the answer is 50 or above.

Comment: sounds like a homework :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should go check out [how to build an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because we wont be coding for you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Post some code. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: all of it don't know what to do im the dumb kid

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
    sum = 0
    while sum <=50: 
        val1 = int(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
        val2 = int(raw_input("Enter the second number:"))
        sum = val1+val2
        if sum >= 50:
            print "The sum is: "+sum
```

Use the above code. Hope it works.
But this is an infinite loop, until the sum becomes 50.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 sum=0;
 while sum <= 50:
  num1=input("enter first value ");
  num1=float(num1);
  num2=input("enter second value ");
  num2=float(num2);
  sum=num1+num2;
  print("sum of ",num1," and ",num2," is ",sum);
```